# How to get the imformation of tray with QtPrintSupport?

Tags: qt, printing, pyside6

I have a copier which has 4 tray (casette) at least.

For example, `QPrinterInfo.availablePrinterNames()` returns the names of copiers.

Like this, is there a way for getting the imformation of paper tray?

I can see this imformation with `QPrintDialog`, it seemes the copier offers this gui but Qt doesn't.

(translation)
default(auto)
auto,
tray1,
tray2,
tray3,
tray4,
LCT,
manual feed

[image]

Comment: QPrintDialog shows the native system dialog on macOS and Windows. The [`setPaperSource()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#setPaperSource) function allows its setting, but Qt won't be able to check whether the value is actually applied or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found out `QPrinter.supportedPaperSources()`.

The result is as follows:

PySide6.QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PaperSource.Auto

PySide6.QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PaperSource(257)

PySide6.QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PaperSource(258)

PySide6.QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PaperSource(259)

PySide6.QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PaperSource(260)

PySide6.QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PaperSource(1000)

PySide6.QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PaperSource.Manual

Probably 1000 is LCT. 257, 258, 259, 260 are tray1, tray2, tray3, tray4.

There doesn't seem to be enough explanation of what is 1000, 257, 258, 259, 260...

Comment: Those are internal enumeration for "custom sources" that are specific to the printer driver. Considering the limited support for paper sources (which is only available on Windows), I doubt that there's a direct way (from Qt, at least) to get the actual names. As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprinter.html#supportedPaperSources): "The values will be either a value that matches an entry in the QPrinter::PaperSource enum or a *driver spesific value*."